# Restricting access with VPC Peers or Transit gateway connectivity

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have two VPCs - VPCA and VPCB.

VPCA will make api calls to the kubernetes control plane on VPCB. VPCB will ultimately becomes many VPCs all with their own Kubernetes cluster and control plane.

In VPCA I have a couple services that will be making these calls.

I'm reluctant to peer subnet in VPCA with subnet in VPCB as I don't want VPCB to be able to connect to all services in VPCA subnet, potentially. I understand, i can secure services in VPCA with security groups, but someone could make a mistake.

I could create a new subnet in VPCA, and put the eks worker nodes for those couple services in VPCA in there and then just peer that new subnet in VPCA with the subnet in VPCB.

But, is there a better way to do this? I've heard of vpc privatelink, but I understand there's an additional cost with that.

Thanks.